# Resize Application name in action bar

Tags: android, xml, resize, android-actionbar

In my application I have 4 buttons in the Action Bar. I added `android:showAsAction="always|withText"` to each `item` in the xml file in order to force show all 4 of the icons. 
I am testing the app on a 4.0" screen, and in vertical view I see the application icon on the left, the app name is cut, and then i see the 4 icons/buttons. For example, the app name is Pandemic, and with all 4 icons in the action bar, i see Pan...

How can I have the application name text resiz to dynamically to fill between the app icon and the left most icon on the action bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar) (search for "How many actions will fit in the main action bar?")
you should show but 2 actions on a 4" display.
Of course you can show more actions but then you run into the problem you encountered. Also these recommendations are design guidelines and it makes sense to follow them to offer a good user experience. Having four buttons next to the title makes the action bar too crowded IMO.

I see a couple of options you can pursue:

1. Use android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" instead of "always|withText"
2. Use a split action bar to allow Android to show the actions at the bottom on the screen if  there isn't enough space at the top. It would still show the actions at the top on tablet sized devices. See also http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar
3. Use a custom layout for your title to make the title smaller. I wouldn't recommend this because it would violate the design guidelines at least implicitly. If you still want to go down that path you need to create your own layout for the title using

   actionBar.setCustomView(newTitleBar, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.LEFT))

To start with a custom layout just copy the one Android is using from your SDK folder.

Comment: On a 4.0" screen, the 4 action buttons show up without the text next to them on the Vertical view. On the Horizontal view, they show up with the text. The issue is, in the Vertical view - when all 4 action buttons show up - because i set `android:showAsAction="always|withText"`, the app name gets truncated. How can I adjust the text size of the title to fit between the app icon and the left-most action button
?

Comment: My point is not that you can't but that you shouldn't. I updated my answer to reflect that line of thinking.

Comment: I wish there was an easy way to resize or completly remove the app name.

Comment: You can remove the title completely or replace it with a custom view.
ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false) would remove the title and actionBar.setCustomView(), actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true) would set a custom view.